# How to get longest consecutive same value?

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

How to get the rows of the longest consecutive same value?

Table `Learning`:

| rowID | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

Longest consecutive value is 1 (`rowID` 8-10 as `rowID` 1-2 is 2 and `rowID` 6-6 is 1). How to query to get the actual rows of consecutive values (not just `rowStart` and  `rowEnd` values) like :

| rowID | values |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |

And for longest consecutive values of *both* 1 and 0?

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzTjXmHMdndrnytP7SstK2/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one approach is to use the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowID) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY values ORDER BY rowID) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        MIN(rowID) OVER (PARTITION BY values, rn1 - rn2) AS minRowID,
        MAX(rowID) OVER (PARTITION BY values, rn1 - rn2) AS maxRowID
    FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY values ORDER BY maxRowID - minRowID DESC) rnk
    FROM cte2
)

SELECT rowID, values
FROM cte3
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY values, rowID;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest approach is to use a window count to define the islands. Then to get the "longest" island, we just need to aggregate, sort and limit:

```
select min(valueid) grp_start, max(valueid) grp_end 
from (select t.*, sum(value = 0) over(order by valueid) grp from testing t) t
where value = 1
group by grp
order by count(*) desc limit 1
```

In [the DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzTjXmHMdndrnytP7SstK2/1) that you provided, the query returns:

| grp_start | grp_end |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 10 |

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess I phrased the question poorly and I edited my original question. I was wondering how to get the actual rows of the longest consecutive same value, not just the starting row and the ending row. Is the only way to achieve this through creating another query where rowID is between groupStart and groupEnd? Or can you do it by modifying the original query? If it is possible to do it by modifying the original query, would you be able to provide a db for this? Thanks.